# @nestjs/schedule throw Error: Unknown alias: fal

Tags: node.js, nestjs, node-cron

I have a nestjs project which runs scheduled tasks, but when I try to run it on Ubuntu 22.04, it throws an error when starting the application. This is the error
`Error: Unknown alias: fal`. Stacktrace below

Error: Unknown alias: fal
at /home/ashan/Source/holistic-theory/node_modules/cron/lib/time.js:403:11
at String.replace ()
at CT._parse (/home/ashan/Source/holistic-theory/node_modules/cron/lib/time.js:398:20)
at new CT (/home/ashan/Source/holistic-theory/node_modules/cron/lib/time.js:96:9)
at new CJ (/home/ashan/Source/holistic-theory/node_modules/cron/lib/job.js:62:19)
at /home/ashan/Source/holistic-theory/node_modules/@nestjs/schedule/dist/scheduler.orchestrator.js:56:29
at Array.forEach ()
at SchedulerOrchestrator.mountCron (/home/ashan/Source/holistic-theory/node_modules/@nestjs/schedule/dist/scheduler.orchestrator.js:54:18)
at SchedulerOrchestrator.onApplicationBootstrap (/home/ashan/Source/holistic-theory/node_modules/@nestjs/schedule/dist/scheduler.orchestrator.js:27:14)

Comment: What do your cron expressions look like? Do they contain localized aliases? https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron/issues/296

Comment: I need this to run everyday at 10am, so I use this `0 10 * * *`

Comment: I guess `false` is being passed to `node-cron` somehow (and logged as `fal`). I don't have a Ubuntu machine at hand but you could try to debug it by placing a breakpoint in `node_modules/@nestjs/schedule/dist/scheduler.orchestrator.js:54:18)` and inspecting why `options.cronTime` is getting parsed as `false`.

Comment: my bad, seems I had mixed up the config and a false was passed instead of the cron expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because instead of a cron expressions like * 10 * * *, the value false was being passed as an input